# How to determine current PBX status (calls, ringing, etc. etc.) with asterisk-dotnet

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am using asterisk-dotnet, and I am looking for a way to get the current PBX "status".
What I need is to determine:

- which extensions are busy in a call
- which extensions are ringing
- which number is calling the extension
- which number is called by the extension
- and the extension number itself.

I know that I can obtain part of these data by using the Status Action, the ExtensionState Action and the NewChannel Action. However these work when an event happens. For example, if an extension is busy on a call, I'll have a new ExtensionState only when the call ends (when the channels are dropped and the peer is available again).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked Asterisk changelog. It appears that a CoreShowChannel action has been introduced in Asterisk 1.6. I still have to do my homeworks, but I guess that's all I need to get info about what's going on the server at my app startup time. 
After this initialization, event tracking is easier as there are already many events that one can subscribe to in order to be notified about new calls, hangs up, etc.
Hope this can help someone else.
Cheers,
Gianluca.